# Like button seemingly disregards og:locale setting

Tags: locale, facebook-opengraph

I have

```
<html lang="en">
```

and

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="da_DK" />
```

The facebook debugger says under "object properties"

```
og:locale: da_dk
```

Based on this information the like button renders in Swedish, which is probably taken from my browser. I would expect, and like, it to respect the og:locale. I have probably missed something simple, but I don't get it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like button renders in the language you used in the url to all.js.  My example below use en_US for the locale.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```